# Abstract for my bachelor's thesis

Tags: grammar, tenses

My supervisor told me that I have wrong tense in my abstract - "You use passive form but it should be active!"
E.g.: "A data model was formed." is wrong according to him but I do not know what I should use. Maybe: "Thesis has formed a data model." ?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Unfortunately, proofreading questions are off-topic on this forum. If you have a question about a specific part of the text we will be happy to help, but as it stands the post is subject to closing.

Comment: @Cascabel Ah OK, I am sorry. Did I fix the question properly?

Comment: Even when the boss is wrong, the boss is right. Choose your battles wisely.

Comment: _Who_ formed the data model? Unless "Thesis" is the name of the researcher, I do not think that sentence works.

Comment: So, are you telling me that my former version (A data model was formed.) is the right version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A data model was formed" is the passive form.  It's not incorrect, but the passive form has gone out of fashion in scientific writing.  It's not as easy to read as the active form, and is rather dull.

"I have formed a data model" would be an active form (assuming that you did it - otherwise replace the "I" with whoever did do it).  The active form emphasizes that science is done by people, and is not just something that happens by itself.